# selectbox display the same div

Tags: jquery

I want selecbox to show div.

no matter what I choose in the selectbox I want to display the same div

I took this code:

```
$('#Field16').bind('change',function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

What do I need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the html code, too.

Comment: What is happening now? What is the issue? How does your html look like?

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XKLx8/ @PSL

Comment: @Roi Your fiddle seems to be working fine...

Comment: $('#id_of_div').show();

Comment: I want it to be different - no matter what I chose (in the selectbox) - the div (I have only 1) will be showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#Field16').bind('change',function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#id_of_div').show(); 
});
```